# jQuery - toggle class by child position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a grid for dynamically generated posts. First post should be full-width and all subsequent posts should be half-width (so they form two columns.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row expanded test">
   <div class="large-6 columns" style="background-color: blue;">One</div>
   <div class="large-6 columns" style="background-color: yellow;">Two</div>
   <div class="large-6 columns" style="background-color: green;">Three</div>
</div>
```

I tried this jQuery script but it doesn't work:

```
$('.test > div').each(function() {    
    $this = $(this);        
    if ($this.is(':first-child')) {
        $this.replaceClass('large-12 columns'); 
    } 
    if ($this.is(':last-child')) {
        $this.addClass('end'); 
    }
});
```

Any idea how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know `replaceClass` is not a jQuery method.

Comment: Did you mean, @i76, [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)?

Comment: You could use `$this.switchClass('large-6', 'large-12');`.

Comment: @Huelfe: That method, too, is not a jQuery method.

Comment: You are right. My mistake. It is in jquery ui. :)

Comment: replace `replaceClass` with [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) and try again :) now: You got 3 news `<div>` they get replace when the next 3 are created? the new news are created one by one or just loaded on the existing `<div>`? if all you want is to format the way the `<div>` are being displayed, I believe you should use just CSS.

Comment: You are right. I changed it to 
$this.removeClass('large-6 columns').addClass('large-12 columns'); 
and it works! Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `$('.tester > div')` to `$('.test > div')`.

You have only a div with `test` class.

Also, there is no `jQuery` **replaceClass()** method. You have to use `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()` methods.

> **removeClass()** method removes a single class, multiple classes, or all classes from each element in the set of matched elements.
>
> **addClass()** method adds the specified class(es) to each element in the set of matched elements.

```js
$('.test > div').each(function() {

    $this = $(this); 

    if ($this.is(':first-child')) {
        $this.removeClass().addClass('large-12 columns'); 
    } 
    if ($this.is(':last-child')) {
        $this.addClass('end'); 
    }
});
```

```css
.large-6{
  width:60px;
}
.large-12{
  width:100px;
 }
.end{
  width:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row expanded test">
      <div class="large-6 columns" style="background-color: blue;">One</div>
      <div class="large-6 columns" style="background-color: yellow;">Two</div>
      <div class="large-6 columns" style="background-color: green;">Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandru-Ionut!

Answer (score 0):

hi please use below code then you will get exact output

```
<div class="row expanded test">
   <div class="large-6 columns" style="background-color: blue;">One</div>
     <div class="large-6 columns" style="background-color: red;">
        <div class="large-3 columns" style="background-color: yellow;width:302px;float:left">Two</div>
        <div class="large-3 columns" style="background-color: green;width:301px;float:left">Three</div>  
     </div>  

</div>
```